VBA Selenium Arrow Down not working in for loop
I created an Excel list of image locations to be sent to Web Whatsapp in Chrome. I am using Selenium with VBA. The first image is sent correctly with its caption, however, from the second item in the list and on, the Sendkeys ArrowDown does not work. For some reason, the focus goes to the address bar in Chrome and I am not being able to make it happen.
Here is the code I use:
wsi is defined as WorkSheet
BOT is the Webdriver

1199      Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
1200      With wsi
1210         For i = fline To lline
1220             PicLocation = .Cells(i, 1).Value
1230             ImageCaption = .Cells(i, 2).Value
1215             If PicLocation <> "" Then
                    ' Before trying to send anything, check if file exists
1250                If FSO.FileExists(PicLocation) = False Then
                       GoTo NextIteration
1260                End If
1265                'BOT.FindElementByXPath(xPathSearchInputField).WaitDisplayed(True).Click
1270                BOT.FindElement(By.XPath(AttachmentButton)).WaitDisplayed(True).Click
1290                BOT.Wait (1200)
1300                BOT.SendKeys ks.ArrowDown
1310                BOT.Wait (1200)
1320                BOT.SendKeys ks.ArrowDown
1330                BOT.Wait (1200)
1340                BOT.SendKeys ks.Return
1350                BOT.Wait (1700)
1360                Application.SendKeys (PicLocation)
1370                BOT.Wait (1500)
1380                Application.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
1390                BOT.Wait (1500)
1395                'BOT.FindElementByXPath (xPathCaption)
1400                BOT.SendKeys (ImageCaption)
1410                BOT.Wait (DefaultDelay)
1420                BOT.SendKeys (ks.Enter)

1435            End If
NextIteration:
1440            Next i
1450         End With

